# Using find for complex AND/OR string search

Tags: command-line

I use a script using find to search my multimedia collection.  This previously worked until I began to add movie trailers, all of which use the naming format *-trailer.*

I want to use find to locate all files matching `*.mkv`, `*.mp4`, or `*.avi`, while excluding any file containing the string fragment `"-trailer."`, even if it matches the first criteria (ie, exclude file moviename-trailer.mkv).  However, the following includes all trailers in the result.

```
find . -type f -iname '*.mkv' -or -iname '*.mp4' -or -iname '*.avi' -not -iname '*trailer.*'
```

I have changed the order of search without success, by trying to first exclude all trailers, and then search on the remainder.

I suspect that find encounters a file such as *-trailer.mkv, flags this as true and prints it, and then looks for the next file, before getting to the condition of excluding it.

Is there a way to nest the search with parenthesis following this logic: find all files (`*.mkv` OR `*.mp4` OR `*.avi`) and not (`*-trailer.*`)?

Thanks much.

Comment: Vookimedlo's response worked perfectly.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
duda@coolomet:~/test$ touch a.mp4
duda@coolomet:~/test$ touch a-trailer.mp4
duda@coolomet:~/test$ find . -type f -iname '*.mkv' -or -iname '*.mp4' -or -iname '*.avi' -not -iname 'trailer.'
  ./a.mp4
  ./a-trailer.mp4
duda@coolomet:~/test$ find . -type f \( -iname '*.mkv' -or -iname '*.mp4' -or -iname '*.avi' \) -and -not -iname '*trailer.*'
 ./a.mp4
duda@coolomet:~/test$
```

You need to do a proper logical expression and have proper wildcards in iname arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`find . | grep -P '^(((?!-trailer).)*\.((mkv|avi|mp4)))$'`

will return

```
./movie.avi
./movie.mkv
./movie.mp4
```

when the current directory contains the files

```
./movie-trailer.avi
./movie-trailer.mkv
./movie-trailer.mp4
./movie.avi
./movie.mkv
./movie.mp4
```